# Extbase-DISTINCT Values from repository

Tags: extbase

Fetch unique room numbers from my database.

My table is tx_example_domain_model_room which has columns startdatetime, enddatetime and roomKey. I want to fetch roomKey greater than given datetime. When I query, the results returns all the roomKey that are greater than given datetime, all the roomKey having more than the given datetime comes up. However, its not distinct. I want to get the distinct rooms. Below is my code:

List.html List

`f:form.select options="{roomKeys}" optionLabelField="roomKey"`

Could you let me know how to get distinct values. One more detail: Room is a model that contains the attributes roomKey, startdatetime and enddatatime.

- Controller

  ```
      $roomKey = $this->roomRepository->RoomKeyFetcher($enddatetime, $startdatetime);
      var_dump($roomKey);
      $unique_rooms = array_unique($roomKey);

      $this->view->assign('roomKeys', $unique_rooms);
  ```

Repository:

```
public function RoomKey($enddatetime, $startdatetime) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $query->statement('SELECT * FROM tx_example_domain_model_room
                        WHERE startdatetime >= ? OR enddatetime <= ?', 
                        [$enddatetime, $startdatetime]);

    $results = $query->execute();

    return $results;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `DISTINCT` keyword on `roomkey` should do it.

```
$query->statement('SELECT DISTINCT roomKey FROM tx_example_domain_model_room
                   WHERE startdatetime >= ? OR enddatetime <= ?', 
                   [$enddatetime, $startdatetime]);
```

Comment: Distinct does not work. I have tried it before.This is the error: Unknown column 'roomKey' in 'field list'. Although roomKey is a field of room model.

Comment: Are you sure the column name is `roomkey` ?

Comment: Yes, the model has the property, roomKey